# My hat falls off my avatar in "recent reviews" image

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, winter-bash-2013

On [MSO Review Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review), my avatar has no hat where the "recent reviews" are listed on that page.

The hat is working fine everywhere else, including on the stats pages, eg:
`meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats`

Where it's missing seemingly doesn't even attempt to show it, as the `div class="hat"` is not in the code.

Issue is the same for Stack Overflow.
Missing on `stackoverflow.com/review` page only, ok on all other pages including the stats pages.

Not perturbed at all by it, but thought I'd report in case it helps (with code management or whatever).

Comment: Seriously? A downvote ? :D haha. - @michaelb958'saSleigh thanks (funny edit comment.. :))

Comment: now, we've hats on recent reviewers queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unacceptable. Let there be hats!

<sup>(I haven't put a hat into the stats popup though; when you look at that popup, chances are you actually want to see the stats and not have them obscured by a hat).</sup>

Comment: When does the chat fix come? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Give me ten minutes :)

Comment: Not only ten minutes, but also ten metarep points when this is done :-)

Comment: Alright. It took twelve minutes. Close enough :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't award you twelve rep points for that :-)