# Ability to filter Winterbash hats page

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013, filtering

It would be nice to have the ability to filter the [Winterbash hats page](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) by site, so that you could see which hats you have on a particular site.  Currently, you have to click on each hat to determine what sites you have earned it on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the leaderboard. For example, on Stack Overflow, the leaderboard is [here](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com), and when filtering by name,

[image]

Unfortunately it will only show a certain amount of your hats, sorted by difficulty.

Comment: That only shows 9 hats.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - It is as close as there is. Perhaps it should be expandable.

Comment: That's one alternative, though I'd like the big page that has all the explanations underneath the hats so I can study them to figure out what I need to be doing.

Comment: [Consider adding it to the list of feature requests for next year.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213574/what-should-we-consider-for-next-years-winter-bash)