# What will happen to the hats when Winterbash is over?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Will there be a record of who had which?  Will the data be made available via the data.stackexchange site?

Comment: No. They disappear. Take a screenshot if you want to.

Comment: pics or it didn't happen

Comment: If you have something specific in mind, you can add a feature request for next year (or vote for one of the existing requests) in this question: [What should we consider for next year's Winter Bash?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213574/what-should-we-consider-for-next-years-winter-bash)

Answer (score 6):

The hats will be done. Gone. Finished. Never to return again. Thrown down a black hole. The hat code rolled back. No 2013 hats to ever be seen again. Ever. Even if you really really want them. The 2013 hat table will be `DROP`ed. The 2013 hat data will never return. Although many like hats, they are not unlimited. SE will destroy the hats, rip them out of our clutching grasp. The hat link will disappear. The hat chooser thing will go away. No avatars will be seen wearing hats. Even though hats are fun, they cannot last. The `<hats>` cannot hold. Hats cannot be kept after Christmas. from the sp​here I can see hats can you see ̲͚̖͔̙hats they is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the hat​s are coming! s of Man ALL HATS IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the hat an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ HATS ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ.

---

With all due respect to [the awesome answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1849664)

Comment: That stopped being funny in 2009... no need to keep milking a dry cow.

Comment: @yoda Do dry cows produce dry milk?

Comment: The vote count on this post is fun. _gets popcorn_

Comment: @qwertynl You get air out the udders.

Comment: This is not how to milk a dry cow. You do that by [asking about Easter eggs in apt-get](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92185/whats-the-story-behind-super-cow-powers).

Answer (score 4):

> It is pitch black. They are likely to have been eaten by a grue.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq):

> After January 3rd, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

Comment: I'm kinda sad that'll I'll lose my pirate treasure hat, though. :S

Comment: I'm still bummed about losing my hats from last Winter :(