# Can we have a Royal hat next year?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash, hat-request

Getting my hat request in early. I noticed a distinct lack of any *royal* headgear this year. No crowns, no tiaras, nada. May I suggest a royal hat next year, perhaps this one, sported by Her Royal Highness Princess Beatrice Elizabeth Mary of York at the Royal Wedding?

[image]

Since the hat was at first widely ridiculed, became a sensation in its own right, and was then [sold at auction for £81k to raise money](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-13495705), perhaps on of the following situations could trigger it?

- Editing a post with net negative votes resulting in it getting net positive votes?
- Getting [reversal](/questions/tagged/reversal) or [populist](/questions/tagged/populist) (highlighting the fact that the hat upstaged the princess on this occasion)?
- The hat was divisive, some people loved it some people hated it. A post that gats >5 upvotes and >5 downvotes on meta?

Comment: lol! I like it. Although the hats are supposed to have a *meaning* behind them that is related to how they are earned. What would the connection be here?

Comment: @Pëkka It's definitely up there in terms of notable contemporary hats. It made [£81k](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-13495705) in a charity auction after much public ridicule. Maybe some connection to 'making the best out of a bad situation', or 'turning something bad into something good'?

Comment: Yeah, maybe something like a [reversal badge.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) Hard to game, too.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question, but just FYI, we're collecting ideas over at [What should we consider for next year's Winter Bash?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213574/what-should-we-consider-for-next-years-winter-bash)

Comment: [Obligatory picture](http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2011/may/04/princess-beatrice-royal-wedding-hat)

Comment: I don't know if I should upvote, because I like the idea, or downvote, because that hat is hurting my eyes...

Comment: We'll never be royals...

Comment: @jonsca You can marry up!

Comment: I can't even marry down.

Comment: I was joking about http://youtu.be/nlcIKh6sBtc ;)

Comment: But we'll never be _royals_

Comment: Welp, you wanted a royal hat, and you got a facehugger. Close enough.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Spoiler alert!

> [image: balpha's avatar with the requested hat]

PS: Hats!

Comment: This is glorious.

Comment: Is it just me or does it look like a toilet bowl?

Comment: @Mysticial No, that's about right. The same is true for the original though, as you can see on the photo in the question :)

Comment: @Mysticial but a royal bowl.

Comment: @Shadow Porcelain throne?

Comment: I hope we are having a kiwi hat this time too.

Comment: I stand [my spoiler](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4rSTx.jpg)

Comment: Is it true that pinging you gets a secret hat?

Comment: hey @balpha, does lyfe matter now that it is part of the standard -- are you going to give up on lyfe.... hope not.  :)  Also, it is not a hat if it has a collar.

Answer (score 17):

## Yes.

But, you'll probably see it unlocked by *using the power that a monarch commands*, which is broadly ceremonial. Maybe you'll have to grant a pardon, or give something a stay of execution. Or perhaps you'll have to 'knight' someone by being the vote that causes them to unlock a privilege.

There are many possibilities, but I think it would be a crime against humanity to not include such gaudyness in next year's hard-earned headgear.

<sub>Disclaimer: I know very little about monarchs, except that they're born in cocoons.</sub>

Comment: Hmmm. *Being the vote that causes them to unlock a privilege*. Is that what this year's man-of-mystery hat is about? Though it would have to be more specific than that, given how few of this hat have been awarded.

Comment: Giving the vote that unlocks a privilege would be *far* too easy to game, but *receiving* a vote that unlocks a privilege would be harder (and would likely increase participation on smaller/newer sites where people have lower rep).

Comment: If you do the 'knight' thing, don't forget bounties.

Comment: I was thinking of reversing the avatars of 5 users, then flipping them again to the original state. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Or maybe you'll just have to stick around long enough...

Answer (score 3):

How about the royal hat goes to the people in the top 10 people of every week during winterbash?

**OR**

`<antiMonarchistRrant>`since it's a royalist hat, how about you get it for being the spawn (AKA sock-puppet) of a 10K user`</antiMonarchistRant>` (Thanks Pëkka)

Comment: But that would mean you actually have to *work* for the hat. `</AntiMonarchistQuip>`

Comment: That was a half-joke, half-shameless plug answer

Comment: Also, that stallman beard on you is downright scary and amazing