# What exactly is the Fan-hat-ic hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

With the [Fan-hat-ic](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/fanhatic) hat what is based off from? I swear I've seen that design before but i just can't think of where.

Also if the reason isn't obvious, why is it associated with fanatics (which is what i assume the pun fan-hat-ic came from?)

Answer (score 13):

It's from this:

[image]

Source: [Can we have a Royal hat next year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214536/180276)

> May I suggest a royal hat next year, perhaps this one, sported by Her Royal Highness Princess Beatrice Elizabeth Mary of York at the Royal Wedding?

Comment: What is that... *thing*?

Comment: @Zizouz212 A toilet seat channeling Cthulhu. (Assuming you mean the hat.)

Comment: THAT WOMAN IS CLEARLY POSSESSED BY THE SPIRIT OF AN ELDER GOD. WE ARE DOOMED. DOOOMED. THE HAT IS OUR DOOM. THE HAT WILL SAVE US ALL. THE HAT WILL EAT YOU FIRST. THE HAT WILL FINISH YOU LAST. THE HAT IS A PORTAL TO A DARK REALM OF HATTERY. FEAR THE HAT. LOVE THE HAT. (Imagine this with more zalgo)

Comment: What an odd way to flag a question as a duplicate. :P

Comment: Comment on one of the posts or comments of the one who flagged this as duplicate and voila you earned a hat.

Answer (score 5):

It's [Princess Beatrice's Wedding Hat](http://www.ebay.com/blogs/stories/princess-beatrices-wedding-hat):

[image: a funny hat]

Answer (score 0):

It likely comes from the Fanatic badge.

To earn the Fanatic badge, you need to visit the site for 100 consecutive days. The Fan-hat-ic hat is likely a play on the words, and similar to the badge itself: to earn the hat, you must visit for 10 consecutive days during the winter bash time period.