# What's wrong with paying with bacon?

Tags: bug, unicoins

I just wanted to buy more unicoins using the "alternative payments - valuables - bacon", but this procedure fails. What should I now do with all this prepared bacon?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer would be to make a bacon hat:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Lady Gaga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Gaga%27s_meat_dress) already showed what to do with your bacon:

[image]

[Edited to add]
And besides: [Proverbs with bacon](http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/keywords/bacon/)

Answer (score 0):

Transit of bacon from shores afar is problematic. It would also adversely effect the allied currency porkcoins so has been outlawed by global convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can take all your bacon and send it to me. I will give you some unicoins, depending on the quality. Warm is prefered but not essential

[Somebody to buy unicoins with bacon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227578/somebody-to-buy-unicoins-with-bacon)