# Somebody to buy unicoins with bacon?

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, unicoins

I don't understand who could even think about spending bacon in unicoins rather than eating it. But in the opposite way it looks perfect to me, i mean, spend my unicoins to get some bacon.

So, having that the [payment with bacon is not available at this point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227498/whats-wrong-with-paying-with-bacon), i'm glad to offer myself as an alternative and unofficial point of sale, effectively accepting bacon as a payment.

If you want to buy some unicoins, please send as much bacon as you can. I will mine a lot of unicoins  and send it to you in the Unicorn Express after cleared payment is received.

Any [kind of egg dishes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_egg_dishes) will be also accepted.

Comment: the question will be deleted (since it is off-topic), and some great replies will be lost. I think it doesn't bother anyone and i will cry!  Thanks for the fun guys!

Answer (score 25):

The problem is probably because nobody is using the right bacon, with some logic thinking I found out that you have to use the special unicorn bacon strips:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Bacon Bacon Bacon Bacon Bacon Bacon Bacon Bacon

Comment: **1)** _Egg and Spam_ **2)** _Egg, Sausage and Spam_ **3)** _Egg and Bacon_ **4)** _Egg, Spam and Bacon_ **5)** _Egg, Spam, Sausage and Bacon_ **6)** _Bacon, Spam, Sausage and Bacon_ **7)** _Bacon, Egg, Bacon, Bacon, Spam and Bacon_ **8)** _Bacon, Bacon, Bacon, Egg and Bacon_ **9)** _Bacon, Bacon, Bacon, Bacon, Bacon, Bacon, Baked Beans, Bacon, Bacon, Bacon and Bacon_ **10)** Lobster Thermidor aux crevettes _with a_ Mornay _sauce, garnished with_ truffle pâté, _brandy and a fried egg on top, and Bacon._

Comment: That's right sir.

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly an illicit use of bacon! You can't legally mail it, because it is a dangerous (ly awesome) substance.

Please follow all [Bacon Regulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davis%E2%80%93Bacon_Act) to ensure that bacon is transported safely. Otherwise, I have no qualms with your plan, and I wholly support your (ab)use of unicoins.

Answer (score 1):

In the event a pig eats your unicorns its perfectly expectable to turn the pig into bacon and use the bacon to buy more unicorns.

But you could of course chose to eat the bacon yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If I send you Bacon, will I recieve Unicorns, or maybe even better: Unicorn Bacon?

I'm willing to trade 2:1, but can only ship over [aether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether).