# Unicorns, unicoins...It's doing my head in. How far will it go?

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins, unicorns

What is the solution to this problem?

Any medicine? Any advice?

Really enjoyed it by the way at first, but now I am hooked up on it.

Comment: May I recommend some time on Facebook.

Comment: Ehehe been there, nothing. Need something stronger.

Comment: Pokémon hunting in Google maps should clear your head.

Comment: Brilliant, Google Android rules

Comment: @d689p It's also on IOS xx

Answer (score 3):

Take the day off, two homeopathic aspirins and you'll be fine.

Comment: What are you implying? if it is what I think of, then Germany is closer to the country of this sort of remedy.

Comment: @d689p You asked for advice and which medicine to take. Actually I only understood this because I'm so much on the (US centered) Internet 'cause in Germany (or Austria where I'm from) this day has been totally unspectacular my whole live.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a solution.

However, there's 1 single medicine that works like a charm!

RAINBOW BACON!

[image: rainbow bacon!]

Comment: [How did you find this amazing unicorn bacon? =o](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227596/218170)

Comment: Credits to @Daanvn by the way.