# Why is the hat called 'Mmmm Bacon'?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

It's not awarded yet, but the participation hat for December 30th (give or take a few [timezones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/295232)) will be [Mmmm Bacon](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/mmmm-bacon).

[image]

That's wonderful, because almost<sup>*</sup> everybody here loves bacon<sup>[citation needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227498/whats-wrong-with-paying-with-bacon)</sup>. However, why is this hat awarded on December 30th only? The other date-based hats<sup>**</sup> all correspond to Christian, Jewish or other kind of holidays:

- [Bûche de Noël](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/b%C3%BBche-de-no%C3%ABl): [Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas)
- [Epiphany](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/epiphany): [Epiphany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(holiday))
- [I Have A Little Dreidel](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-have-a-little-dreidel): [Hanukkah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah#Dates)
- [First Responder](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/first-responder): [New Year's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year's_Day)

What is so special about December 30th? Or did the Hats team just choose a random day?

<sup>*</sup><sub>: apologies in advance to those who don't eat bacon for religious reasons and/or vegetarians</sub>
<sup>**</sup><sub>: there's another date-based hat, but it's secret so we can't talk about it</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's not an official holiday, and people over the world are celebrating it on different days of the year, like the first Monday of September, some American people celebrate National Bacon Day on [December 30th](http://www.baconday.worldbreak.com).

More information can be found in the <s>links</s> advertisements<sup>*</sup> below:

- https://jbsfatboy.com/december-30-is-bacon-day/
- https://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/bacon-day/
- https://phoenixchamber.com/2016/12/16/dec-30-is-national-bacon-day-savor-your-way-through-the-valley-for-a-bacon-fix/

<sup>*</sup><sub>: I'm not affiliated with any of them.</sub>

Comment: In case you're wondering: yes, I had to Google this.

Comment: Seriously, why are our answers like seconds apart?

Comment: @PythonMaster mine was a self-answer, which I posted at the same time as the question.

Comment: I mean like our answers are often seconds apart

Comment: I type faster than you :) But for this one, I had a tremendous advantage.

Comment: Was this for the Egoist hat? I see you're top of the mse winterbash leaderboard but not wearing any hat!

Comment: @MartinSmith I like my hats without wearing marks :)

Comment: I like my hats without wearing marks too