# Winter Bash hat causes User Card Overflow™ on old self-answers

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, firefox, user-card

In case of a self-answer, the user card for the answer has a blue background. In the latest Firefox on macOS Monterey, the Winter Bash hat moves the 'answered' information to the right, making it overflow this background. This is only noticeable for old answers where the year is shown; [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288797/295232) is an example:

[image]

Before the Winter Bash features load (I'm on a rather slow connection), it is shown normally. I am not able to reproduce it in other browsers.

Comment: Sort of able to reproduce on Chrome on Android. JS loads slow here. There is a visible jump in place for the date, and the final rendering lacks padding between the date and the box. The date just hugs the box's edge.