# How to get my previous Hat on Winter Bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I am playing Winter Bash every year, but unfortunately the Hats are missing now?

How can I get my previous Hats in Winter Bash 2014, 2015, 2016?

Is there any page that can I access?

There is only [this page to see](http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015) or [this page to see](http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2016).

---

**How to get the screenshots of my previous years?**

*If we cannot get the result of the previous year, what is the purpose of Winter Bash? Only for the profile picture?*

Comment: I've [asked for such a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213580/223467) back in 2014. It didn't happen since, and it doesn't look as though there's any intent to implement it.

Comment: @Mureinik why bother? Those who really want can easily save screenshots.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's exactly what I've been doing since 2014 ;-) But it's not as neat as having something exportable that you can actually navigate afterwards.

Comment: @Mureinik true, but that would require lots of efforts on SE side, and personally I prefer they'll spend them on more useful things. :)

Comment: how to get the screenshots of my previous years? if we cannot get the result of the previous year? what's the Winter Bash purpose?? ONLY for profile picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The hat page is only for the year, and you cannot wear or see previous years hats

[As per the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/)

> As for the rest of us: we have from today (December 13, 2017) through January 2nd, 2018 to catch ‘em all. After that date, all the hats go back into storage, never to be seen again… unless the Greatest Hats make an appearance in another 5

## NEVER TO BE SEEN AGAIN!

Comment: how to get the screenshots of my previous years? if we cannot get the result of the previous year? what's the Winter Bash purpose?? ONLY for profile picture?

Comment: Its to get people to use the site during what's traditionally a lull period. The exclusivity of hats to that period probably helps